# Migrating Django project from production to local SQL server

Tags: django, django-models

I have Django project which is working fine in production(using Mysql as Database). I am running Mysql server locally in my PC(using XAMPP) , i have a done appropriate changes in setting.py as shown below.

BUT when i try to run "python manage.py migrate MYAPP" i am getting an error as shown below.

```
Also tried different command (same error)
--> python manage.py syncdb 
--> python manage.py makemigrations MYAPP
--> python manage.py runserver
..etc.,
```

It is not creating any table in SQL backend , any suggestion ?

```
Settings.py

DATABASES = {
'default': {
'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
'NAME': 'MYAPP',
'USER': 'root',
'HOST': '127.0.0.1',                 
'PORT': '3306',
 }
 }
```

ERROR

```
 _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'MYAPP_DB.TABLErole' doesn't exist")
```

Answer (score 1):

Suggesting your working on a current django release: `python manage.py syncdb` is deprecated. Instead use `python manage.py migrate` to apply django's core migrations.

Than make and apply your own migrations:

```
python manage.py makemigrations MYAPP 
python manage.py migrate
```

To get a list of all available and applied migrations use:

```
python manage.py showmigrations
```

Comment: Still same error. and i dont see any table in Database

Comment: Which django version do you use? Do you see any migrations when you run `python manage.py showmigrations`?

Comment: I am using python 3  & Django 2.1.5.

Comment: In production i see some migration, but once i make changes in setting (for local SQL DB) . I see same error (django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'MYAPP_DB.TABLErole' doesn't exist"))